# Will upgrading hosting improve performance of slow WordPress plugins

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, performance

I have built a website for a community  in the last year. In the last few days I realised that it has become a very slow one.

I found out that two plugins (Polylang and All In Event Calendar) causes a lot waiting time. If I deactivate them then the website is fine. These two plugins put a lot stress on the server.

I use the GTmetrix website to  check for optimization the sites. According to this site the webpage is well optimised (could be better anyway).

My question is if I would upgrade the host it would make much difference? Now I use the Business package at 123reg and I would go with the premium S. Both shared host.  There is no money for VPS.

Comment: Have you tried installing [a caching plugin](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=site:wordpress.org+caching+plugin)?   I've found that adding cache can improve performance of my WordPress sites.

Comment: Hi, Yes I have installed the W3 Total Cache plugin. On GTMetrix the website gets PageSpeed Score A 94% and YSlow score B 81%.

Comment: You could also try to find replacement plugins.    I'm using this event calendar: https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might but will depend on the host. Some plug-ins are just a huge drag no matter what you do. When you think about it adding extra features via plug-ins might be great for users but slow site will have a reverse effect for UX.

My recommendation is something like WP Engine. They tailor their hosting just for WordPress. Using them also eliminates the need for caching plug-ins. They have all of that running for you on their end. I use them fro about 20 clients and never had a performance issue. I would check the [Disallowed Plug-ins](https://wpengine.com/support/disallowed-plugins/) page first to make sure that none of yours are on the list.

I would stay away from GoDaddy WP hosting because it doesn't really show much improvement in performance when comparing to their standard shared hosting. Basically, stay away from any of the usual suspects like DreamHost and etc. VPS are also not a good option due to cost especially if you can only afford the non managed ones.

Also, I would look for alternatives for the plug-ins that are giving you trouble. I know that there are a ton of Event Calendar plug-ins out there.